# CodeGolf - Heads or Tails

Tags: code-golf, string

#### Instructions

Given an unknown input string `i` with a value of either *heads* or *tails*, return `1` for *heads* or `-1` for *tails* with the shortest code.

#### Sample not golfed code (55b):

```
if(i == "heads"){
    print(1);
}else{
    print(-1);
}
```

#### Sample golfed code (16b):

```
print("t">i||-1)
```

---

*Javascript was used for the example but it's **not** a requirement*. Sorry if it's too simple for most users, it can be improved.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is too simple to be an interesting challenge. In the future, please consider posting challenges to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), where they can get feedback before posting them live.

Comment: 6 answers, not so a bad challenge indeed. Try again

Comment: Got down voted to earth, can't see the score but at least there are four down votes, I'm not trying again, sticking to so

Comment: At 4 upvotes and 5 downvotes, your question wasn't really unpopular; it just got mixed reviews. While the task at hand is a little basic, it is well-defined and attracted 7 answers so far which feature several different approaches. Not that bad for a first attempt.

Comment: Let's see if I can at least score 0 and maybe I'll post the next one, I have so many ideas for puzzles..

Comment: @JuanCortés Don't give up on making puzzles; it might be hard starting out, but once you get the hang of it, it'll be a whole lot more fun.

Comment: I'm so confused right now, yesterday -4, now +4, this sure ain't stackoverflow :P

Comment: I've been waiting for a short challenge like this for ages, most of the challenges are too long and complicated for a novice like me.

Comment: I don't think you'll have to post a golfed example in the question – better do this as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## CJam, 4 bytes

```
I'e#
```

Assumes that the variable `I` holds the input, since `i` isn't a valid identifier in CJam.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22heads%22%3AI%3B%20e%23%20Store%20input.%0AI'e%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Execute%20code.%0AS%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Push%20a%20space.%0A%22tails%22%3AI%3B%20e%23%20Store%20input.%0AI'e%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%23%20Execute%20code.%0A)

This is equivalent to the JavaScript code `I.indexOf('e')`.

Comment: Probably unbeatable for this challenge.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the requirements enough and made a fool of myself with this question. I'll go back and hide now

Comment: Why do you not include the `p` in this? Is it standard in CJam not to?

Comment: @Tim CJam always prints the stack contents at the of the program automatically.

Comment: @Tim: The question says to *return* 1 or -1, so I assumed leaving the number on the stack would be fine. I've edited the permalink to show that `p` is not needed.

Answer (score 18):

### C, 18 bytes

Pretty easy, but let's do it just for fun...

```
puts("-1"+*i/8%2);
```

Given the string `char *i` it prints 1 for `heads` and -1 for `tails`, with trailing newline.

### Explanation

In C, `"-1" + 1` points to 1 character forward, so it is the same as `"1"`. Let's take a look at the first characters:

```
"heads"[0] = 'h' = 104 = 0b01101000
"tails"[0] = 't' = 116 = 0b01110100
```

If we count the bits from the rightmost one starting at zero, bit 3 is 1 in `heads` and 0 in `tails`: summing it to `"-1"` gives the right string. It looks like this:

```
"-1" + ((i[0] >> 3) & 1)
```

Now, substitute `i[0]` with `*i` and the right shift with the power-of-two division to save some bytes. Also remove useless parentheses:

```
"-1" + (*i / 8 & 1)
```

Now, `& 1` can be substituted with `% 2`. The character count is the same, but the modulus has higher priority, allowing to drop the parentheses. Remove the whitespace:

```
"-1"+*i/8%2
```

### Bonus

I think the shortest way to get an integer 1 or -1 (not a string) in C is:

```
18-*i/6
```

Explanation:

```
'h' = 104
't' = 116

('h' + 't') / 2 = 110
110 - 'h' =  6
110 - 't' = -6

(110 - 'h') / 6 =  1
(110 - 't') / 6 = -1

Apply distributive property (integer division):
18 - 'h' / 6 =  1
18 - 't' / 6 = -1
```

Comment: Beautiful, love it

Answer (score 12):

## Ruby, 8 (6 without output)

```
p ?t<=>i
```

Rocketship operator!

Comment: Clearly the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 9):

### PHP - 11 Bytes

```php
<?=1-$i^=F;
```

This works because `'tails' ^ 'F'` → `'2'` and `'heads' ^ 'F'` → `'.'`, which when typed as an integer is `0`.

You may test this solution (or any of the below) in the following way:

```php
<?php foreach(['heads', 'tails'] as $i): ?>
 <?=1-$i^=F;
endforeach; ?>
```

[Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/kLyO5M)

---

**Alternatives**

*15*: `<?=1-md5($i)%3;`
*16*: `<?=md5($i)[5]-5;`
*16*: `<?=-crc32($i)%5;`

Comment: With the short version I'm always getting a 1, care to explain what it does with the XOR?

Comment: @JuanCortés I've added an explanation, and a link to Ideone.

Comment: Now that's thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC, 9-10 bytes

```
cos(πʳinString(Ans,"t
```

Straightforward. "t" is in position 1 of "tails", but "t" is not in the string "heads", so inString( returns 1 for tails and 0 for heads.

If your calculator is in radian mode (as any mathematician's should be), it takes only nine bytes:

```
cos(πinString(Ans,"t
```

Note that TI calculators do not have named strings, so the input is in the calculator's answer variable. Also note that lowercase letters are two bytes each, so this solution actually takes less memory than than the word "heads".

Comment: This is awesome. Your byte count is off, though-- cos(, π and the radian symbol are all one byte, so it's actually 8-9 bytes.

Comment: The `t` and `inString(` are each two bytes.

Comment: Oh, I'd forgotten about lowercase letters being two bytes. Never mind, then.

Answer (score 5):

## [Fission](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fission), <s>26</s> 21 Bytes

```
O/';'1
"S@]_"-
R? <tL
```

Martin (and his excellent answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50858/31054)) convinced me to learn a new language, and what better place than a quick golf? This is almost certainly not optimal, but hey, it was fun! Once I feel good about it, I may provide some form of explanation if it is requested.

Answer (score 5):

## x86-16 machine code, 8 bytes

As a callable function, input string at `DS:SI`, output in `AL`.

```
80 3C 74    CMP  BYTE PTR[SI], 't'      ; if 'h': CF = 1, if 't': CF = 0 
1A C0       SBB  AL, AL                 ; AL = AL - AL - CF (AL = -CF) 
                                        ;  if 't': AL = 0 and CF = 0
                                        ;  if 'h': AL = -1 and CF = 1 
1C FF       SBB  AL, -1                 ; AL = AL - (-1) - CF 
                                        ;  if 't': AL = AL + 1 = 1
                                        ;  if 'h': AL = AL + 0 = -1
C3          RET
```

#### x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 17 bytes

Or as a standalone DOS COM executable. Input from command line, output to stdout.

```
00000000: b402 0826 8200 7a04 b22d cd21 b231 cd21  ...&..z..-.!.1.!
00000010: c3
```

**Unassembled:**

```
B4 02           MOV  AH, 02H        ; DOS API display char function     
08 26 0082      OR   DS:[82H], AH   ; set parity flag from input 
7A 04           JPE  HEADS          ; if even, heads - display just '1'
B2 2D           MOV  DL, '-'        ; otherwise first display a '-''
CD 21           INT  21H            ; output DL to console
            HEADS: 
B2 31           MOV  DL, '1'        ; display the '1'
CD 21           INT  21H            ; output DL to console
C3              RET
```

**Explanation:**

Use the CPU's parity flag to determine if first char is an `'h'` (even number of binary `1`'s) or a `'t'` (odd number of binary `1`'s). This saves one byte over comparing the char in ASCII.

**Input/Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## C, 22 bytes

```
puts(*i>'h'?"-1":"1");
```

<sup><sub>Credits goes to [@TheE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40904/the-e) [for telling me about this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50270/quickgolf-heads-or-tails/50284#comment119324_50284)!</sub></sup>

Explanation:

If the first character of the string is greater than `'h'`, the string `"-1"` is printed. Otherwise, the string `"1"` gets printed. Note that this approach comes with a trailing newline character.

---

Old version (25 bytes):

```
printf("%d",*i>'h'?-1:1);
```

Explanation:

If the first character of the string is greater than `'h'`, -1 is printed. Otherwise, 1 is printed.

Comment: i just said t before , use i as type char , the actual definition would exceed by 1byte like this return -(-1)**i/16

Comment: @Agawa001 , But that returns 6 for `h` and 7 for `t`.

Comment: oh i forgot , i must use power :p

Comment: Cool guy unfortunately C doesnt have such arithmetic operation thus u have to use -1*pow(-1,*i/16) which makes it waaay longer, in other hand, python and matlab use ** and ^

Comment: @CoolGuy would using puts `puts(*i>'h'?"-1":"1");` not be better? (22 bytes)

Comment: @TheE , Good idea. I hadn't thought of `puts` as I have to print a number and `puts` is used to print a string. Thanks!

Comment: While keeping the conditional core, you can use the method I used in my answer by flipping the statement: `puts("-1"+(*i<'t'));` or `puts(&"-1"[*i<'t']);` are both 20 chars.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo , Awesome! I really liked `puts(&"-1"[*i<'t']);`! You can add that in your answer as it is your idea. BTW, I'm truly impressed by your answer. Its just cool. *Very* cool indeed. :D

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 16 bytes

```
print(i<'t')*2-1
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 4 bytes

---

```
 xz"e
```

Run with [heads](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xz%22e&input=heads&debug=0) or [tails](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=xz%22e&input=tails&debug=0). As `i` is `int` in Pyth, this uses `z` as the variable name, which contains any user input. It is equivalent to the Python `print(z.find("e"))`, so uses @Dennis's method.

Answer (score 4):

## VBA (Excel), 12 bytes

Not a fantastic bit of golfing, but it's fun to try with VBA to get anywhere near to a proper programming language...

```
?13-asc(i)/6
```

i is the string, and it just exploits the ASCII value of the first character, divided by 6 and substracted from 13 to give 1 or -1. Very simple.

Example run in immediate window (10 extra bytes to set the input variable) :

```
i="Heads":?13-asc(i)/6
 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## Tr: <s>17</s> 13 characters

(Or <s>14</s> 10 if you count only the arguments…)

```
tr -s ta-s -1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ tr -s ta-s -1 <<< heads
1

bash-4.3$ tr -s ta-s -1 <<< tails
-1
```

Brief explanation:

`tr` stands for transliterate, that means, replaces each character of the input found in the first argument with character at the same position in the second argument:

```
tr ta -1 <<< tails         # replaces t ⇢ -, a → 1
⇒ -1ils
```

If the first argument is longer, the characters without positional match in the second argument are replaced with second argument's last character:

```
tr tals -1 <<< tails       # replaces t ⇢ -, a → 1, l → 1, s → 1
⇒ -1i11
```

When `-s` (`--squeeze-repeats`) option is used, successive characters which would be replaced with the same character are replaced at once:

```
tr -s tals -1 <<< tails    # replaces t ⇢ -, a → 1, l+s → 1
⇒ -1i1
```

So if we enumerate all characters in “tails”, we get what we need:

```
tr -s tails -1 <<< tails    # replaces t ⇢ -, a+i+l+s → 1
⇒ -1
```

Same for “heads”, but wee need to keep the “t” in front to consume the minus (characters sorted alphabetically for creepiness):

```
tr -s taedhs -1 <<< heads   # replaces h+e+a+d+s → 1
⇒ 1
```

Merging all uniques characters of “tails” and “heads” in a single first argument, keeping “t” in front leads to final solution:

```
tr -s tadehils -1 <<< tails # replaces t → -, a+i+l+s → 1
⇒ -1

tr -s tadehils -1 <<< heads # replaces h+e+a+d+s → 1
⇒ 1
```

To avoid enumerating the characters, an interval in *from***-***to* format can be used instead.

Comment: Care to explain it?

Comment: That assumes BSD/GNU `tr`. POSIXly: `tr -s ta-s '-[1*]'`

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
ae
```

[Try it online](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YWU&input=ImhlYWRzIg)

Answer (score 4):

## shell (portable/POSIX), 16 bytes

`expr $i : he - 1`

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/z@1oqBIQSVTwUohI1VBV8Hwf0p@Xur/DKCCYq6SxMycYi4A)
Thanks to [@StéphaneChazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) in [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/536172/265604)

Other solutions tried:
`echo $[30#$i%7-1]               # 17 bytes but only in bash, zsh.` [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikGmtkJL/PzU5I19BJdrYQFklU9Vc1zD2f0p@Xur/DKCKYq6SxMycYi4A)
`echo $((30#$i%7-1))             # 19 bytes but only bash,ksh,zsh.` [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##yy7O@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikGmtkJL/PzU5I19BRUPD2EBZJVPVXNdQU/N/Sn5e6v8MoJpirpLEzJxiLgA)
`he=2;echo $[${i%a*}-1]          # 22 bytes But only in bash,zsh .` [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/z8j1dbIOjU5I19BJVqlOlM1UatW1zD2f0p@XipQLjGlmKskMTOnmAsA)
`a=${i%h*};echo ${a:+-}1         # 23                   .` **portable .**  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/z/RVqU6UzVDq9Y6NTkjX0GlOtFKW7fW8H9Kfl7q/wygumKuksTMnGIuAA)
`he=2;echo $((${i%a*}-1))        # 24 bytes             .` **portable .** [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/z8j1dbIOjU5I19BRUNDpTpTNVGrVtdQU/N/Sn5eKlA2MaWYqyQxM6eYCwA)
`IFS=h;set $i;echo ${1:+-}1      # 26 (change IFS)      .` **portable .** [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/9/TLdg2w7o4tURBJdM6NTkjX0Gl2tBKW7fW8H9Kfl7q/wyg0mKuksTMnGIuAA)
`(IFS=h;set $i;echo ${1:+-}1)    # 28 (subshell)        .` **portable .** [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/1/D0y3YNsO6OLVEQSXTOjU5I19BpdrQSlu31lDzf0p@Xur/DKDiYq6SxMycYi4A)
`(IFS=h;set $i;echo $(($#*2-3))) # 31 bytes             .` **portable .** [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopBprZCS/1/D0y3YNsO6OLVEQSXTOjU5I19BRUNDRVnLSNdYU1Pzf0p@Xur/DKD6Yq6SxMycYi4A)

Note: Using `dash` as a reasonable simile of a portable shell tester.

- `expr $i : he - 1` works by counting how many characters match `he` with `$i : he`. A `heads` match `2` and a `tails` match 0 (none).Then substracting `1` with `- 1`.
- `$[30#$i%7-1]` works by converting the string to an integer. The base 30 and the mod by 7 were selected to obtain a difference of 2 between `heads` and `tails`. Then subtracting 1 converts the numbers to `1` and `-1`.
  Note that a `$[...]` is an archaic form of arithmetic expression `$((...))` valid only in some shells.
- `he=2;echo $[${i%a*}-1]` works by making a variable of some value and then using Arithmetic Expansion to expand that variable (from the text value). The `${i%a*}` converts `heads` to `he` and `tails` to `t` (that, as a variable, has a value of 0).
- `IFS=h;set $i;echo ${1:+-}1` works in two steps. Setting IFS to `h` breaks the unquoted `$i` in `set $i` into parts divided by the character `h`, `heads` is divided to `''` and `'eads'`, thus setting `$1` to null. `tail` is not divided by `h`, thus making `$1` equal to `tails`. Then, `${1:+-}` generates a `-` if the value of `$1` is non-null (as in `tails`) or nothing (as with a null `$1`). That sign (or nothing) is concatenated with `1`.
- `(IFS=h;set $i;echo $(($#*2-3)))` works in a similar way but use the number of parts (`$#`) that the string in `$i` got broken into.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 20 bytes

```python
print(('h'in i)*2-1)
```

This returns `False` if it isn't, and `True` if it is. In python `False` and `0` are the same, and `True` and `1` are as well.

So:

```python
True (1) * 2 -1 = 2-1 = 1
False (0) * 2 - 1 = 0-1 = -1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 17 bytes

```python
print'-1'['t'>i:]
```

`'heads'` is less than `'t'`, so it evaluates to `True == 1`, and prints the string after the first character. `'tails'` is greater than `'t'`, so it evaluates to `False == 0` and the whole string is printed.

If we're doing this from the command line, with implicit printing, it just becomes:

```python
'-1'['t'>i:]
```

...for 12 bytes, but it adds single quotes to the output.

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, 11 bytes

This has got to be the shortest piece of QBasic I've ever written.

```
c=i>"t
?c^c
```

**Explanation:**

The above is some pretty heavily golfed QBasic. Once the autoformatter gets through with it, it'll look like this:

```
c = i > "t"
PRINT c ^ c
```

The first line compares the string `i` with `"t"`. If `i` is `"heads"`, `i > "t"` is false and `c = 0`. If `i` is `"tails"`, `i > "t"` is true and `c = -1`. Yes, `-1` is the default value for boolean true in QBasic!

The second line maps `-1` to `-1` and `0` to `1` via a math trick: `(-1)^(-1) == 1/(-1) == -1`, and `0^0`, though technically mathematically undefined, returns `1`.

This code requires that `i` be explicitly declared as a string variable; otherwise, it would have to be `i$`. Full test program (tested on [QB64](http://qb64.net)):

```
DIM i AS STRING
DATA heads, tails

FOR x = 1 TO 2
READ i

c=i>"t
?c^c

NEXT x
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
'eI(
```

Similar to [Dennis' CJam answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50271/87923), finds the index of `e` in the input string

Saved one byte since I didn't realise input was automatically used as an argument if there isn't enough stack values

## How it works

```
'e  Push e
I   Index of e in the the input. 2 if heads, 0 if tails
(   Subtract One
Stack gets automatically outputted
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/Xz3VU@P//5LEzJxiAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 22

```bash
echo $[0x${1:1:1}/2-6]
```

Takes the 2nd letter (`e` or `a`) and interprets it as a hex digit (14 or 10), then divide by 2 and subtract 6 to get the right answers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T81OSNfQSXaoEKl2tAKCGv1jXTNYv/XcpVnZOakKhSlJqYo5GTmpVorpORzKQABREM1SKzWCiySpqAC4nGl5Oel/s8AaijmKknMzCnmAgA)

Comment: Awesome trick, I'm gonna borrow it :)

Comment: For bash, use: `echo $[30#$i%7-1]` only 17 bytes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)), <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 21 bytes

**`ed`** gave me a headache. Finally figured it out with help from [`@ed1conf`](https://twitter.com/ed1conf/status/1161687587360313355) on twitter and some peeps on [`unix.se`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535595/ed1-script-with-multiple-search-replace). You can't just match things with `s/re/newtext/`, you have to prefix it with `g` otherwise **`ed`** packs a sad. It's like a grumpy 50 year old unix program saying "get off my lawn".

```regex
g/t/s//-
,s/\w\+/1
w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z9dv0S/WF9fl0unWD@mPEZb35CrnOv//5LEzJzi///yC0oy8/OK/@sWAwA)

<sub>***-2*** bytes by dropping the final `/`s

***-4*** bytes thanks to @manatwork (& whose `sed` answer i plagiarised)

*Old version:

`g/t/s//-
g/\w\+/s//1
wq
.`*</sub>

Comment: But you need the address trick only for the 1st command, as the 2nd will never fail. And no need to explicitly `q`, it will quit by itself when nothing left to do. And you only need a newline after them, the “.” (or “roblogic”…) is unnecessary. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z9dv0S/WF9fl0unWD@mPEZb35CrnOv//5LEzJzi///yC0oy8/OK/@sWAwA "ed – Try It Online")

Comment: Ahh thanks I will try your suggestions when I get home. At the pub now 

Answer (score 2):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/) <strike>25</strike> <strike>20</strike> 18

```lua
w(I.r():f'h'&1|-1)
```

<strike>Probably could be golfed some more by using some tricks that I'm not thinking about at the moment.</strike> (see [history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/50290/revisions) for old version) Saved 5 chars by moving input to `write` and ignoring the `if` statement there. Two more chars were saved by ignoring the optional parenthesis on `find`. It does not check for failed conditions (i.e., input that isn't *heads* or *tails*).

A Lua equivalent would be

```lua
io.write(io.read():find('h') and 1 or -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 18 bytes

```
f('h':_)=1
f _= -1
```

Every string starting with the letter `h` is mapped to `1`, all others to `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Sed: 16 characters

```sed
s/t/-/
s/\w\+/1/
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ sed 's/t/-/;s/\w\+/1/' <<< 'heads'
1

bash-4.3$ sed 's/t/-/;s/\w\+/1/' <<< 'tails'
-1
```

Comment: Nice, I used your regex for my `ed` solution, but it still took 23 bytes, because `ed` is old and grumpy!

Comment: `\w` and `\+` are GNU extensions though.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

```apl
3-3⊃⍋
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P03hUdsEBWNd40ddzY96u0EC6iWJmTnF6lxAVkZqYkqxOgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
'eI
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#c=%27eI&i=%22heads%22%0A%22tails%22&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
└0Y.
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c030592e&i=heads%0Atails&a=1&m=2)

It's the codepoint of the first character mod 7 minus 5.

Answer (score 2):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <del>8</del> <del>12</del> 8 bytes

```
_d=2*1-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/PsXWSMtQV@///5LEzJxiAA)

### Explanation (syntactically invalid)

```
_        Take input and discard the last item
 d=      If the top of the stack is d:
   2*    Re-set the top of the stack as 2
     1-  Decrement the top of the stack by 1
       . Explicitly output the top of the stack
```

> -4 bytes thanks to manatwork

Comment: May there be some TIO interpreter version difference? Looks like it doesn't handle neither “heads” or “tails”.

Comment: Now I fixed the program.

Comment: May there be some TIO interpreter version difference? Seems it takes input implicitly and reverses it on any attempt to process inexistent data, making it work without `^`.

Comment: BTW, you not need to discard 4 characters until “t” as the 2nd one “d” or “l” already identifies which input you got. Just have to explicitly output so can leave the unprocessed input on the stack: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/PsXWSMtQV@///5LEzJxiAA "Keg – Try It Online").

Comment: I think I can still -1 bytes by switching to "Reg": [TIO!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/PsXWSMta7///ksTMnGIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 15 bytes

```powershell
($args[1]-99)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DJbEovTjaMFbX0lJT3@h/LReXSoWCrYJ6RmpiSrE6l5pKmoJDBVSsJDEzBy72HwA)

Takes input via splatting. Uses the `e` vs the `a` to do ASCII math

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 8 bytes

```
?z2*1r-p
```

dc can't do anything meaningful with strings other than read them in and attempt to evaluate them.  Doing this, "heads" outputs some warnings about unimplemented commands and empty stack, which we ignore, but importantly the stack remains empty.  "tails" does almost the same with the important exception that the final "ls" loads a value from the s register to the stack.

We then use "z" to get the stack length and arithmetically fiddle to get the right answers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNCoAgFAb37xQf4ipoUcsyOov5HihIRgZB0dntb5YzMJPNvrBziWVQZTzaqlnrpSjafYiCVSwjhll6cCI8iPMJ@nzd1X2GHWqB0v9FwRgD/XbiNEvxzyLTZkPMdAM)

Answer (score 2):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 10 bytes

```
F.~%.7/-_<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/302vTlXPXF833ub//5LEzJxiAA)

Divides the ASCII value of a character input by 7. Subtracts the quotient from 15. Execution stops when the IP runs out of the program space. This works because Triangular can only manage integer division. Conveniently, "h" has a value of 104, which is 14 when integer divided by 7; "t" is 116, which is 16 when integer divided by 7.

Ungolfed/Explanation:

```
   F
  . ~
 % . 7
/ - _ <
---------------------------------------------------------------
F                 - Push 15 to Top of Stack
 ~                - Read a character from input, push its value to ToS
   7              - Push 7 to ToS
     <_           - Change directions, then pop ToS-1 and ToS, push their integer quotient
        -         - Pop ToS-1 and ToS, push their difference
          %       - Print ToS as an integer
```

---

**Previous version (14 bytes):**

```
~\81|m/,!<.>i%
```

Read a character from input; if that character's ASCII value divided by 8 has a remainder, print -1, otherwise print 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
\eḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiXFxl4bifIiwiIiwiXCJoZWFkc1wiXG5cInRhaWxzXCIiXQ==)

Direct translation of the CJam answer (find the index of `e`, or -1 if not found).

Some more fun ones:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
14βǒ‹
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMTTOsseS4oC5IiwiIiwiXCJoZWFkc1wiXG5cInRhaWxzXCIiXQ==)

```
14β     Convert given string from base 14 to integer
        (invalid digits are treated as -1)
   ǒ    Modulo 3
    ‹   Decrement
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
18β±
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiMTjOssKxIiwiIiwiXCJoZWFkc1wiXG5cInRhaWxzXCIiXQ==)

```
18β     Convert from base 18 to integer
   ±    Sign
        "heads" is positive -> 1
        "tails" is negative (because leading digit is invalid) -> -1
```

Comment: Did not expect to see base conversion used like this today. Had to stop for a bit and remember how the implementation of invalid characters works after seeing this. Very clever!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 13 bytes

So what, I'm late for the party. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
zv&v'h'=)i1rN
z             Grab all input.
 v            Capture the top item (h or t) as a temp variable.
  &           Generate new stack, move to it.
   v'h'=      Test if the variable is h.
        )i    If it isn't, push -1.
          1   Push 1.
           r  Reverse the stack.
            N Print out the top item as a number.
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 15 bytes

```
H=2?VAR(I[T])-1
```

Not the shortest possible solution, but I didn't want to post a boring program that's the same as all the others.

The `VAR` "function" converts a variable name into a variable. `VAR("X") = 1` is equivalent to `X = 1`, for example.

The program sets `H` to 2, then uses `VAR()` on the first character in the input string.
(`I[T]` is the same as `I[0]`, because `T` is `0`. I had to include `T` here because `VAR` is not allowed to create new variables).

If the input is `heads`, `VAR()` returns the variable `H`, which has a value of 2.
If the input is `tails`, `VAR()` returns the variable `T`, which has a value of 0.

Then, it subtracts 1 from this and outputs either `-1` or `1`.

Because variable names in SmileBASIC are not case sensitive, this program works for any capitalization of the input string.

Note:
Normally, string variables must have names ending in `$`, but there are several ways to avoid this restriction. The simplest is to put the code inside a function, because function arguments are not type checked:

```
TEST "heads"
TEST "tails"

DEF TEST I
 H=2?VAR(I[T])-1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Homespring](https://github.com/quinkennedy/Homespring), 50 bytes

```
youth. fountain bear 1 pump heads    -1 pump tails
```

very simple, make the input salmon young, block him after he enters the right branch so he spawns early, then bear eats the downstream input salmon

Comment: What does make the input salmon young mean?

Comment: Could you add a [tio link](https://tio.run/#homespring) so others can easily verify the solution?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, bears eat all mature salmon, so without making the input salmon young it would be eaten by the bear before it has a chance to spawn. This way it can slip past the bear, but matures again after spawning.

Comment: @FrownyFrog, tio doesn't appear to be entering the input properly. I tried a small sample program, `bird`, which should return the input, but didnt get any output. I doubt i'll use homespring again but maybe i'll throw up an online interpreter if i cant find one

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (PET, VIC-20, C64/128, C16/+4, TheC64Mini) 44 Tokenized and BASIC bytes

```
 0b$="heads":inputa$:?-1*(b$=a$)+1*(a$<>b$)
```

Commodore BASIC returns `-1` as `TRUE` and `0` as `FALSE`, so a bit of simple maths is required to output the right required answer here.

[image: Commodore VIC-20 Heads or Tails]

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, <s>25</s> 19 bytes

-5 bytes using @Digital Trauma's [bash solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189918/15940); get the second letter, either `e` or `a`. Then `0xe` and `0xa` are interpreted as hex, i.e. decimal `14` and `10`. Then we do a bit of arithmetic to output `1` or `-1`.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGJdqgQqXaMNootlbfSNcs9v///yWJmTnFAA)

```zsh
<<<$[0x${1[2]}/2-6]
```

24 bytes: 
`<<<${1[1]:s/h//:s/t/-/}1`

25 bytes: 
`<<<${1[1]:s/h/1/:s/t/-1/}`

Comment: I need to stop following you around... [13 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190212/86147)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 10 bytes

```perl
$_=o cmp$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jZfITm3QCX@//@M1MSUYq6SxMyc4n/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Comment: Old I know, but 7 bytes with flag abuse: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbBTdfo//@M1MSUYq6SxMyc4n/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULctw0MjQB

Answer (score 1):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 16 bytes

I will expand it later.

```
?-ň*8+94{1}{-1}
```

### Explanation

```
?               If statement
 -ň             Subtract input with
   *8+94        The ASCII code of h
        {1}     If true, return 1
           {-1} Otherwise, return -1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'ek
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPTX7//@M1MSUYgA) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf/XU7P86/zNSE1OKuUoSM3OKAQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
'ek '# Get the 0-based index of "e" in the (implicit) input-string
     # (or -1 if no "e" is present)
     # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 7 characters

```
t=-
*=1
```

Generally the same thing as [my Sed solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50506) does, but there is a big difference: Sed executes all commands on the pattern space (so later commands act on previous command's result), while Gema handles each piece of input once and discards it.

So although in the 1<sup>st</sup> step Gema's `t=-` does the same as Sed's `s/t/-/`, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> step Gema's `*=1` will act either on “ails” or “heads”, while Sed's `s/\w\+/1/` has to handle either “-ails” or “heads”.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema 't=-;*=1' <<< 'heads'
1

bash-5.0$ gema 't=-;*=1' <<< 'tails'
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/v8RWl0vL1hDISMzMKQYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*-1 from @Isaac*

```sh
<<<$[#1%7-5]
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPVZxaoqCrq6ACEvhvY2OjEm1ooatsqG8W@z8lHyiUAVRdzFWSmJlTzAUA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJLPVZxaoqCrq6ACEvhvY2OjEq1sqGquaxr7PyUfKJIBVFzMVZKYmVPMBQA)

> `man zshmisc`, under *Arithmetic Evaluation*:
>
> > An  expression  of  the  form  `##x`  where  x  is any character sequence such as `a`, `^A`, or `\M-\C-x` gives the value of this character and **an expression of the  form  `#name`  gives  the value  of  the first character of the contents of the parameter name.**

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>52</s> 34 bytes

```
({}[{}()()()])({<{{}}>[()()]}()<>)
```

<s>Output is the top element of the stack</s>

-18 bytes thanks to Jo King

[Try it with heads!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6Nrq6VkMTBGM1Naptqqtra@2iwVygsI2d5v//GamJKcX/dRMB)

[Try it with tails!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6Nrq6VkMTBGM1Naptqqtra@2iwVygsI2d5v//JYmZOcX/dRMB)

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6Nrq6VkMTBGM1Naptqqtra@2iwVygsI2d5v//GamJKcX/dRMB). Try to combine consecutive pops and pushes, especially in that first section

Comment: Oh wow, could you make an explanation, since I don't really understand the second part?

Comment: [Explanation](https://tio.run/##LY6xDsIwDET3fMWNrUQZmCt@grFiMNTQiBBXjaGCKN8e0hZZliX73p0vE1nf3Bw9cq5i6mKq6qXOtamAk9KkGF9hMIiAvcGLb748yQ52z1CyLhgAbUwxHYFRRujSs@BN7sUBwTr26j6LrCvGZYD6Hp7vpPbNEM8GCWDfw0mBZ6vDRqM5LKH/mKpujxtbEFCRP6XwKhAdeEJQuj5Mvf7758tt3ea8euSGfg) plus another byte saved in the loop

Answer (score 1):

## C-INTERCAL, 177 bytes

This is my first, and hopefully last, INTERCAL program. INTERCAL is a truly remarkable language. Those who haven't heard of it should immediately investigate ([here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/home.html#04) is the manual I used).

```
PLEASEDO,1<-#2PLEASEDOWRITEIN,1PLEASEDO.1<-',1SUB#1'~#4DO(2)NEXTDO,1SUB#1<-#76(1)DO,1SUB#2<-#40(2)DO(3)NEXTDO,1<-#1DO,1SUB#1<-#116DOCOMEFROM(1)DOREADOUT,1(3)DOFORGET.1DORESUME#1
```

The program reads from standard input and writes to standard output. After printing the appropriate string, the program crashes with one of two humorous error messages depending on the input.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##TctPC4JAEIfhD7MHFTZpNrFLF2vHEFon9g92lRIKokN17qtvo2B0nGd@7@3xHp7n/h7j8YCVQ00SNguh5quzjcemlTBDzu9EggtbAclHFJpSlbV48mM5KefrMoVsBsVQLHnF09Vvygj/CUCpaUcGa0tmqi1WmoKXwJWmmuwefQ6ju2BQQIzXob@8vg)

### Ungolfed

```
    PLEASE DO ,1 <- #2
    PLEASE DO WRITE IN ,1
    PLEASE DO .1 <- ',1 SUB #1' ~ #4
    DO (2) NEXT
    DO ,1 SUB #1 <- #76
(1) DO ,1 SUB #2 <- #40
(2) DO (3) NEXT
    DO ,1 <- #1
    DO ,1 SUB #1 <- #116
    DO COME FROM (1)
    DO READ OUT ,1
(3) DO FORGET .1
    DO RESUME #1
```

Well, that didn't help much...

In the first three lines, we read 2 (`#2` in INTERCAL) characters from the input into array `,1` and store in variable `.1` whether the first character read has bit 2 set (mask of 4); in ASCII `h` is `0b1101000` and `t` is `0b1110100`, so this variable now indicates whether the input is `tails`. This uses the "select" operator `~`, which in this case performs both masking and shifting to select bit 2 as 0 or 1.

The rest of the program is an if/else conditional and a print statement. Unfortunately, control flow is very limited in INTERCAL. The only mechanism is a call stack that's pushed to when the program executes `DO (x) NEXT`. `DO RESUME #1` then operates like a return statement (but with no return value), popping the stack and jumping to the next statement after the most recent `DO (x) NEXT`. But the value passed to `DO RESUME` can be any number. `DO RESUME #3` pops the call stack three times and jumps to the third-from-last `DO NEXT`.

A similar construct is `DO FORGET`, which only pops the stack the specified number of times but does not jump. `DO RESUME` always jumps, so passing it 0 is a run-time error. But the instruction `DO FORGET #0` is valid, and doesn't do anything.

And so with the statements `DO (2) NEXT` and `DO (3) NEXT` I push two locations onto the call stack. At `(3)` I then discard `.1` frames, which has the effect of "forgetting" the call at `(2)` if and only if the input was `tails`. As a result, we end up just after either `DO (2) NEXT` or `DO (3) NEXT` after the return on the last line, depending on the input.

Each branch then loads the appropriate character data into `,1` (see [here](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/s05.html) for why the values don't make any sense), and `COME FROM (1)`, an inverted `goto`, joins the two branches at the output statement `DO READ OUT`. Control then continues, but luckily in either case the program crashes before printing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 18 bytes

```java
i->i=="heads"?1:-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BasMwEETP0VcMgoINtiDXuE5vhRxyyrHtYWtLrlxFNt51IJR8u6s0puxhh53Zx/R0obJvv5dx/gy@QROIGUfyET8KWK8sJGldBt/inLzsJJOP3dsHaOo4/4sCfWKZWXwwbo6N@CGa11U8Px4KHKLYzk57ONSLL/e@rvWXpZb1y3ZXbpdK/aPFsjDqBN@skSIpIR9Yq1ul3DBhLQLG7pG/d9mcriz2bIZZzJhscZl@YrxHXcAZGsdwzTjPK3W7z/IL)

Comment: Welcome! This is a well-golfed solution but when the input is `heads` it only works when `i` is [interned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) because of the reference comparison (`==`). For this reason strings are usually compared in Java using `String#equals`. Your TIO works because your inputs are string literals, but this approach doesn't work in general. I don't think assuming strings are interned/literal is typical on here, so you should probably make sure your solution doesn't rely on that.

Comment: @Jakob yeah, [but it's 25 now...](https://tio.run/##PU7BbsIwDD2Tr7AiIbVSG4krHeyGxIETx20Hr02Ku5CW2kFCiG/vwqgmH/zk9/ze6/CKZdf8TEP89lRD7ZEZDkgB7gpgvrKgpHXtqYFz4rKjjBTajy/AseX8TwrQJS8ThbxxMdRCfTC7Gby9HgrYB7GtHbfgYDNRuSVjLxE9Z/pksWGdv6/W5Wqq1H@CWBaGTcpYzJoiIUHyrNWjUq4fYe4DDOuX/llpcbyx2LPpo5gh0eIyvWT4DLoAZ3AY/C3jPK/U4znTLw)

Comment: True, but it works for any input, which is the most important thing. Now the question is can you find a shorter version? (I think you'll find there's a 17-byte solution).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 14 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.search`e`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NauWK84NbEoOSMhNeF/QVFmXolGQkZqYkqxgq1CgnYalJOgqckFlSxJzMyBS4I5QMn/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
2-2{/:
```

Same approach as FrownyFrog's [APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178222/110888). -2 thanks to Bubbler

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxzEjXqFrfCsLZpcmVmpyRr5CmZqegnpGamFKsbq1ekpiZU6wOUbBgAYQGAA)

```
2-2{/:
    /:  NB. grade up
  2{    NB. take the third item
2-      NB. subtract from 2
```

Comment: `2-2{/:` is the more direct translation.

Comment: Oh. I've got egg on my face. I thought `i.` was happening...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 18 bytes

```py
print(i.find("e"))
```

`str.find` returns `-1` if it can't find the required character. In `heads`, `e` is in position 1 (Python is 0-indexed), whereas in `tails` it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

### Befunge, 28 bytes

28 bytes including whitespace and newlines:

```
<v"heads"
 >94+%v
,,"-1"_1.@
```

Assumes that either `heads` or `tails` is put into the string above (this is the equivalent of assuming the input is stored in `i`). Works by performing modulo 13 on the top character on the stack - `h` divides exactly, `t` does not.

I also made a 22 *character* version (excluding whitespace/newlines) but the input has to be backwards:

```
"sdaeh"v
       9
       4
       +
       %
@,,"-1"_1.
```

Comment: You can make this code shorted by using `d` instead of `94+` to get the number 13.

Answer (score 0):

## Unefunge 98, 15 or 16 bytes

```
'h-4j@.-1_1.@
```

The above code assumes input is stored on top os the stack in **reverse order**. There are two 16-byte solutions that don't make this assumption:

```
$'d-4j@.-1_1.@
```

Assuming input is on top of the stack in normal order.

```
~'h-4j@.-1_1.@
```

Reading input from stdin

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

```r
for(i in scan(,''))print(`if`(utf8ToInt(i)[1]%%8,-1,1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzixoCCnUqM4OTFPQ0ddXVMnrTQvuSQzP0@jUjMhMy1Bo7QkzSIk3zOvBCgQbRirqmqho2uoY6ip@V89IzUxpVidS70kMTMHRHtA@SEwvqujSzCI7@jpE6z@HwA)

Really poor attempt, but I the `utf8ToInt` values for `"h","H","t","T"` are 104, 72, 116, 84 respectively. As a result, `"h" and "H"` values are both evenly divisible by 8, while `"t" and "T"` are not. So a conversion and check for even divisibility yields the desired results.

This method compared to the following method takes different spellings of heads/Heads/HEADS/etc. and tails/Tails/TAILS/etc. As long as it starts with an h/H or t/T it will work properly.

EDIT: -3 bytes switching to a for loop. Prints each value on newline instead of a single array of 1's and -1's.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
for(i in scan(,''))print(ifelse(i=="heads",1,-1))
```

This method was suggested by @user5957401 and is much simpler. The difference here is that this method assumes that the user will input strictly "heads" or "tails" (technically anything but "heads").

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SCNTITNPoTg5MU9DR11dU7OgKDOvRCMzLTWnOFUj09ZWKSM1MaVYScdQR9dQU/O/OpirzqVekpiZA6I9oPwQGN/V0SUYxHf09AlW/w8A)

Comment: ifelse(i=="heads",1,-1) seems like a quicker way to vectorize

Comment: That's pretty simple actually, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I'll add yours in.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 40 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   S _Read_input_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S S S T  T   T   N
_Push_7][T  S T T   _Modulo][S S S T    S T N
_Push_5][T  S S T   _Subtract][T    N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace inputs one character at a time, I use that to my advantage here by only looking at the first character and porting [*@recursive*'s Stax answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189851/52210) (so make sure to upvote him as well!)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4FTg5OYE8IAlmg5hgYSAbKP//f0ZqYkoxAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer c = STDIN as character code-point
c = c % 7
c = c - 5
Print c to STDOUT as integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 12 bytes

```
P110mz6dzcmo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/z/A0NAgt8ospSo5N////5LEzJxiAA)

Requires `heads` or `tails` non-capitalised.

This only accepts the first character of the input. If it needs to accept all input, replace the `P` with `Ij`.

### Explanation

```
P            | Get the first character of input as its ASCII value
             |              ( h | t )
 110mz       | Subtract 110 (-6 | 6 )
      6dz    | Divide by 6  (-1 | 1 )
         cm  | Flip sign    ( 1 |-1 )
           o | Print it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 14 characters

```
index("e")//-1
```

That's searching character position in the string. Unfortunately on not found it returns `null`, so the `//` ([alternative operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://)) has to be used. (Still shorter than an `.[:1]<"i"` check as that results boolean and there is no way to cast that to integer.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq -R 'index("e")//-1' <<< 'heads'
1

bash-5.0$ jq -R 'index("e")//-1' <<< 'tails'
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8zLyW1QkMpVUlTX1/X8P//ksTMnOJ/@QUlmfl5xf91gwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
ab*i-6,n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzFJK1PXTCfP@v//jNTElGIA)

I'm honestly surprised that there wasn't a fish answer yet.

Subtracts the ASCII value of the first character input from 110 and divides by 6.

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 42 bytes

```
,>,+++[-<->]<[-[->+++<]>.>]-[>+<-----]>--.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fx05HW1s7WtdG1y7WJlo3WtcOyLWJtdOzi9WNttO20QWBWDtdXb3//zNSE1OKAQ)

Checks if it is heads or tails by checking if the ordinal values of first two characters are only three away from each other.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes

```
'e=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1891RZIZKQmphSrc6mXJGbmFKsDAA)

Basically identical to a lot of other solutions. Checks the index of `'e'`, and returns `-1` if not found.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (V8) - 19 Bytes

Since OPs solution returns 'true' and '-1' ([see here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfllikkKlgq6CekZqYUqzOBeJngfgliZk5xer/C4oy80o0lEqU7DJranQNNbm4ECJZYJH//wE)), the following function:

```
f=i=>i[0]=='h'?1:-1
```

returns '1' and '-1' - [see here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P80209YuM9og1tZWPUPd3tBK1/B/QVFmXolGmoZ6RmpiSrG6piYXXKQkMTMHJPIfAA). Just to be a smart-ass and so.

// Adaption of [Java (SDK)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190294/74284) version as a JS function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 10 bytes

```
1i3%1C=?Z@
```

[Try it online! (heads)](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98w01jV0NnWPsrh//@M1MSUYgA)
[Try it online! (tails)](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98w01jV0NnWPsrh//@SxMycYgA)

Works by determining if the 4th character is a `d` (compare to number literal 100) and if not, multiplies a `1` by `-1`, then prints and terminates.

```
1              Push 1 (the output)
  i            Read input string
   3%          Get 4th character (0-indexed)
     1C=?      Compare with 100 (decimal value of d)
         Z     If false, multiply TOS with -1
          @    Output entire stack (the only thing left with be a 1 or -1) and terminate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
`e`c[1|u
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiYGVgY1sxfHUiLCIiLCJcImhlYWRzXCJcblwidGFpbHNcIiJd)

u is `-1`.